# qml append json stream to listmodel

Tags: json, qml, listmodel

I would like to append an answer in JSON from a web server to a QML ListModel. Currently I am using

```
eventModel.append(jsonObject)
```

which works fine if the answer only contains strings or numbers but not if there is an array within the answer. I am using the code from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/5626/parsing-json-with-qml/5) to get the JSON object.

This is one line of the answer:

```
{"i":3814086,"t":"d","s":1479970800,"sw":"Do","sds":"24.11.16","ss":"08:00","e":1479996000,"eds":"24.11.16","es":"15:00","f":false,"z":[{"i":223500,"d":true,"r":"","h":null,"hs":null,"hss":"","he":null,"hes":""}]}
```

Everything is added fine beside z. If I read the entries from the list model I get this:

```
{"objectName":"","i":3814086,"t":"d","s":1479970800,"sw":"Do","sds":"24.11.16","ss":"08:00","e":1479996000,"eds":"24.11.16","es":"15:00","f":false,"z":{"objectName":"","count":1,"dynamicRoles":false}}
```

It looks like everything in z is lost. I already tried to add it again

```
for(var i in jsonObject){
    eventModel.append(jsonObject[i])
    eventModel.set(i, {"z":jsonObject[i]["z"]})
}
```

but the result is the same.

Is something like this just not possible or am I doing something wrong here when appending the JSON object to the list model?

Comment: `ListModel` contains list of `ListElement` items. According to [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details) it can contain only simple values - `Values must be simple constants; either strings, boolean values, numbers, or enumeration values`.  Value you try to assign to `z` is object or array.

Comment: To bad I did not see that. I guess there is no work-arround, is there? Because I have no clue on how to work with the JSON if I cannot store it in a ListModel =(

Comment: If I do `eventModel.set(i, {"zn":jsonObject[i]["z"][0]})` zn is added as array and I have all values. Maybe 2D arrays (or what ever z currently is) cannot be added to a ListModel but arrays do work.

Comment: sorry to have you misled. I've tested that and `ListElement` get as arrays as objects. For example it eat that `model.append({param: {a: 1, b: 2}})` w/o problem. Arrays also are acceptable: `model.append({param: [1,2]})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from one of my apps and it can be an illustrative example for your case.

```
ListModel {
        id:agenciesModel

        ListElement {
            name: "401"
            eventListDates :[
                ListElement{
                    date:"jj/mm/aaaa"
                }

            ]
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "402"
            eventListDates :[
                ListElement{
                    date:"jj/mm/aaaa"
                }

            ]


        }

        ListElement {
            name: "403"  
            eventListDates :[
                ListElement{
                    date:"jj/mm/aaaa"
                }

            ]



        }
}
var listObjJS = [{"date":"10/10/2019"},
                 {"date":"10/11/2011"},
                 {"date":"10/11/2011"},
                 {"date":"10/11/2011"}
                ];

for(var j=0;j<listObjJS.length;j++ )
   agenciesModel.get(i).eventListDates.append(
        { date : listObjJS[j].toString().split(":")[1]}
   );
```

Comment: Basically I should convert the 2D array into a 1D array but I do not see how I should store my data so that I could still access it. JavaScrit does not have variable variable names, right? So I cannot apped z1, z2 etc and then do a loop with z+j as variable name...